# How can I change the login resolution in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, resolution

How do you change the resolution of the login screen in Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic)? The login manager is [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager).

Keep in mind that I need to change the resolution of the **login** screen, as explained below.

Comment: what is your login-manager (gdm, kdm, slick etc)?

Comment: I am using gdm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to change the [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager) *login screen* resolution.

[Justin was](https://superuser.com/questions/98886/how-can-i-change-the-login-resolution-in-ubuntu/98887#98887) kind of correct, except the fact that GDM uses the modeline from your *xorg.conf* file. The priority runs from left to right, so if you add "1280x960" as the first entry and remove any items you don't want (who needs half of them anyway, 768x600 or whatever it was, madness), you should be fine for GDM.

```
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1280x960" "1024x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to configure your *xorg.conf* file to include the proper modes.

Edit */etc/X11/xorg.conf*:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Device        "NVIDIA Corporation NV43 [GeForce 6600 GT]"
    Monitor        "17P3"
    DefaultDepth    24

    [...]

    SubSection "Display"
        Depth        24
        Modes        "1024x768" "1280x960" "640x480" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Where the first Mode is the default resolution.

If you have an ATI card you may try this as well:

```
sudo aticonfig --resolution=0,1280x1024,1024x768,800x600
```

Where 0 is the first screen, and the resolutions are in order of preferred first.

Try adding this as a subsection to the 'Screen' section in your *xorg.conf*:

```
SubSection "Display"
        Virtual 1280 800
EndSubSection
```

Comment: ...and this will just change the login resolution, right?

Comment: Not really...resolution is a global setting.

Comment: That's not what I need though.

Comment: Once I'm logged on,  everything is fine, but the login screen has the wrong resolution.

Comment: @George: Ohhh... in that case try it! I thought you wanted different resolutions and not the same, sorry.

Comment: @Bobby: Ya, the GTK desktop is, I believe 1280x800 but the login screen somehow became 2560x1024 and I wanted to fix it. What do I change in xorg.conf? It isn't that I want to add a resolution, but simply reset everything to 1280x800.

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: Try this as well.  Add this text as a subsection to the 'Screen' section

        SubSection "Display"
                Virtual 1280 800
        EndSubSection

Comment: @JustinS what do you mean?

Comment: @JustinS Is `Virtual` the name of your display?  If my name is `Virtual1` should I use that name?   And where are the line breaks?  Should it be `"1280x800"` instead of `1280 800`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a special X11 configuration but you do happen to have a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, you might want to try moving it aside and see what happens. Usually X11 should configure itself properly these days and in my experience having stuff in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` often causes problems.

To try without the file:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

and restart.

If it doesn't help move it back:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and restart once more.